# Change "New Event" text in all items view (calendar)

Tags: 2013

As the subject says I want to change the name of the "New Event" Link in a calendar list. (sharepoint 2013)

I found this in F12-Mode:

```
<table id="Hero-WPQ2" dir="none" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr>      <td class="ms-list-addnew ms-textXLarge ms-list-addnew-aligntop ms-soften"><a title="Ein neues Element zu dieser Liste oder Bibliothek hinzufügen." class="ms-heroCommandLink" id="idHomePageNewEvent" onclick='NewItem2(event, "http://sharepointsite/testcalendar/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=8&amp;ListId=%7BB9F033E7%2D7690%2D4CEE%2DAA15%2DF93849EB21E1%7D&amp;RootFolder="); return false;' href="http://sharepointsite/testcalendar/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=8&amp;ListId=%7BB9F033E7%2D7690%2D4CEE%2DAA15%2DF93849EB21E1%7D&amp;RootFolder=" target="_self" data-viewctr="33"><span class="ms-list-addnew-imgSpan20"><img class="ms-list-addnew-img20" id="idHomePageNewEvent-img" src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23"></span><span>Neues Ereignis</span></a></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I want to change the "Neues Ereignis"-Text at the end of the code.

Any ideas how I can change it by using the script editor/content editor?

I found some solutions for SP2010, but they didnt work for me in 2013.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way in pure CSS(2):

```
.ms-list-addnew a:first-child:after{
  content: 'New button name';
}

.ms-list-addnew a span + span{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks MdMazzotti. It works. You are the best :-) I just need to change the a:hover background color and it will work as fine as wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the page, add a Script Editor webpart, then add the following code (requires jQuery):

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("spReady");

function spReady(){
   $('.ms-list-addnew span:last').text("New button name")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way without jquery? only css?

Comment: Not sure if CSS 3 has anything able to replace an existing content (but even if it had, I'm pretty sure the browsers support would be quite limited -I'm especially thinking of older IE versions)

Comment: Ok. The older browser versions would not be an issue. We are only using IE10.

Comment: even IE10 has limited support for CSS3

Comment: @Philipp I added a new answer with the same solution in pure CSS (I took it as a personal challenge LOL)